# Programmable to change Plotly Gauge to display the reminder values in percentage

Tags: python, plotly

How to change the delta to display reminder values in percentage [(total - used) / total] and without any color.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

total_list= [200,300,400,500]
used_list = [160,250,320,400] 


fig = go.Figure()

for i,(v,d) in enumerate(zip(total_list, used_list)):
    #print([0.25*i+0.05, 0.25*i+0.25])
    fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
        value = d,
        delta = {'reference': v}, 
        gauge = {
            'axis': {'visible': False}},
        domain = {'x': [0.25*i+0.05, 0.25*i+0.25], 'y': [0.0, 1.0]}))#{'row': 0, 'column': i+1}))

fig.update_layout(
    grid = {'rows': 1, 'columns': 4, 'pattern': "independent"},
    template = {'data' : {'indicator': [{
        'title': {'text': ""},
        'mode' : "number+delta+gauge",
        'delta' : {'reference': d}}]
                         }}
)
fig.show()
```

Comment: I tried to see if I could do it, but the percent display is a string and the request is an integer or decimal point. Delta values must also be supported. `for i,(v,d) in enumerate(zip(total_list, used_list)):percent = '{:.1}'.format((v-d)/v); fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(value = float(percent),delta = {'reference': 1-float(percent)}, ...)`